# Center Span on screen, not div?

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I'm trying to do a simple image gallery where the span opens on mouse click (by the way i would apreciate help with that too) and shows the enlarged image centered not in its parent div but over the whole screen.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: the parent is a body element.

Comment: You need to add a [mcve] to your question. Nobody is going to debug an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at how to create an Overlay on a screen via JavaScript and CSS it requires some html structure and manipulation but the content is covered at w3schools [http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp]. Code snippet from page is listed below. Although not exact to your desire it is the idea and an implementation that will get you to your exact needs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```